# Why some result of CityData is List[entity]?

Tags: curated-data, entity

Why one entity is a List Object?
There are many such cases.
They are in one level/one region/province.

```
CityData[{"Anqing", "Anhui", "China"}]
(* Entity["City", {"Anqing", "Anhui", "China"}] *)

CityData[{"Bangbu", "Anhui", "China"}]
(* {Entity["City", {"Bengbu", "Anhui", "China"}]} *)
```

[image]

Comment: Please add text instead of screenshots so we can copy/paste/evaluate.  I assume here that one of these is an entity, but the other is an entity class with one member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an old design: if the input matches exactly the standard name, it will return the entity by itself. If the input is not a valid standard name, it will try to find the possible entities the input refers to. In the second case you could have asked without the region for example:

```
In[1]:= CityData[{"Bangbu", "China"}]

Out[1]= {Entity["City", {"Bengbu", "Anhui", "China"}]}
```

Of course, the answer would have been more than one if many cities have the same name, like with *springfield* cities:

```
In[2]:= CityData[{"springfield", "Wisconsin", "UnitedStates"}]

Out[128]= {Entity["City", {"Springfield", "Wisconsin", "UnitedStates"}], 
    Entity["City", {"SpringfieldStCroix", "Wisconsin", "UnitedStates"}], 
    Entity["City", {"SpringfieldMarquette", "Wisconsin", "UnitedStates"}], 
    Entity["City", {"SpringfieldJackson", "Wisconsin", "UnitedStates"}]}
```

In this last case I did input `"springfield"` with lowercase instead of uppercase to avoid matching the exact standardname for the first entity.